# How to style inline Navbar with logo and menu links to the left and form controls to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a code written in html5 in which i have a logo, some nav-links. Also have login form with two text-field and 3 buttons. I want to style in such a way that my logo and navbar links are float to the left side by side and my login form with buttons to the right. i want the exact styling shown in below image

[image: screenshot for final styling]

Html code is:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav-header-main">
      <a class="header-logo" href="index.php">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="mmtuts logo">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-login">
        <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail...">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
            <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <a href="signup.php">Signup</a>
        <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

CSS File:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header-logo img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nak73406/frpu62Lq/3/
You can use `float` to change the direction of the items. Attention to last lines in the CSS

Or use this code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}
nav li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  text-transform: uppercase;
} 
nav li{
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.header-logo img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.logout {
float: right;
padding: 6px;
}
.loginform{
  float: left;
}
.header-login{
  float: right;
}
button[name="login-submit"],button[name="logout-submit"]{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:none;
}
button[name="signup-submit"]{
  background: white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:none;
  
}
button[name="signup-submit"] a{
 text-decoration: none; 
}
input{
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav-header-main">
      <a class="header-logo" href="index.php">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="mmtuts logo">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-login">
        <form class="loginform" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail...">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
            <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
            <button type="submit" name="login-submit"><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></button>
            
        </form>
        
        <form class="logout" action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: here the window is small please check on the fiddle or in your local full width

Comment: yes sir...it worked but how do i style the signup label in between 2 buttons.. i want exactly positioned as shown in the above image i upload

Comment: I will update it for you, I just want to know that you follow up your question

Comment: @NishantNarola I have updated the fiddle and codes to match better your code, but consider that for details you should code your self, also I recommend the bootstrap to use in your project that make your work easy and it has many good styles for the interface.https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: also i have this code below in my index.php, but cant see

Comment: <?php
 require "header.php";
?>

      <main>
        <p>You're logged out!</p>
        <p>You're logged in!</p>
      </main>
      
<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>

Comment: how can i style  that accorfing to the image i uploaded it

Comment: Please add your files and codes completely,  then I can know your code and your idea better, it will be fine to searching first and also opening new question for your problem. I will do anything that I can if you get complete details about problem and supporting by follow up your question

Comment: If this answer for this question works please accept it, thanks for your follow up!

Answer (score 1):

You can try play apply one item float:right;, or use container{ display: flex; } items{order: -1;}
more details :[display: flex;](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: sorry didnt get what u are trying to say